# Restore Html with JQuery, except some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

After an Ajax request, I want to reset my form elements to their original value, except for three select input, because their values are going to be used frecuently.

I declared this variable outside of "document ready":

```
var estado_inicial_cuerpo;
```

I tried this in "document ready" function:

```
estado_inicial_cuerpo=$("#formulario_venta").clone().children('#id_bodega_idbodega').remove().children('#id_caja_idcaja').remove().end();
```

And in the "success" part of the ajax (or if you like, in some button that activates this code), this one:

```
$('#formulario_venta').html(estado_inicial_cuerpo);
```

But, in the console I can see that the page is like loaded two times by using that code, and also, the entire form gets in blank, all the elements disappear.

The ID of my form is `formulario_venta` and `id_caja_idcaja` , `id_bodega_idbodega` are the ID's of the select inputs that I want to skip.

---

Now I tried this inside of the "document ready" code:

```
estado_inicial_cuerpo=$("#formulario_venta").not("#id_bodega_idbodega, #id_caja_idcaja").html();
```

Now the form don't dissapear, but everything is restored, including the elements that I wrote inside "not".

Comment: you're probably not stopping the `submit` event

Comment: @JaromandaX actually I'm doing it, because without that code everyting is working fine. I have this for the form submit: $('#formulario_venta').on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
         //more code here
});

Comment: fair enough, if that's how it's done using jqueery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$('#formulario_venta').find('input, textarea, select').not("#id_bodega_idbodega, #id_caja_idcaja").val("");
```

That way you say all inputs will have `value = ""` (empty) except the one that are inside `.not()`

`.find('input, textarea')` are the type of inputs your form might have

Comment: even better that this would be add a class to all inputs you wan to reset, and then you write only .find('.inputToReset).val(''), without using .not()

Answer (score 0):

How about trying just

```
estado_inicial_cuerpo = $("#formulario_venta").html()
```

Do you have any sample?

Comment: My code is really big, but I'm going to try to make a tiny sample. And I have used that approach to reset only a Select input, but if I use it on the form it will be completely restored, and I want to skip some elements in the restoration, select inputs to be precise. So, that select inputs must mantain their values.

Comment: just throw in the form elements to jsfiddle or codepen for us to play around with.  Alternatively, if the elements are not dynamic, just target the elements you need to be cleared.

Comment: I don't know if this will be work, but I tried this: [https://jsfiddle.net/gcobn8du/1/ ]

Answer (score 0):

**First clear html** from element then assign again.

```
$('#formulario_venta').html('');
$('#formulario_venta').html(estado_inicial_cuerpo);
```

Comment: Assigning directly to `.html()` will do the same. no need to assign empty.

Comment: I tried that, and had the same result, all the form dissapear. I don't know if that "children" and "remove" part do really work.